# Fastest way to find the last date in which the running total became negative

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sum

What I have so far can calculate the most recent date that the running total was negative, however I need the date of when it became negative.  Is this possible without splitting it into multiple temp table / CTE queries to maintain performance?

```
declare @CustomerCode int=2134

select CustomerCode, CustomerType, max(PaymentDate) as MaxPaymentDate
from (
    select b.CustomerCode, b.CustomerType, b.PaymentDate from Payments as a
    join Payments as b
    on a.CustomerCode = b.CustomerCode and a.CustomerType = b.CustomerType
    where b.PaymentDate <= a.PaymentDate
        AND a.CustomerCode = @CustomerCode 
    group by b.CustomerCode, b.CustomerType, b.PaymentDate
    having sum(b.paymentamount) <= 0
) as T
group by CustomerCode, CustomerType
```

For example, in the table below I am looking for the row on date 2021-01-07 because the running total of -10 just became negative and it is the most recent time it became negative.

| CustomerCode | CustomerType | PaymentDate | PaymentAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-01 | 0 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-02 | 10 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-03 | -30 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-04 | 10 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-05 | 20 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-06 | 10 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-07 | -40 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-08 | -10 |
| 123 | retail | 2023-01-09 | 10 |

Comment: please check your sample data again and clarify the expected date, it can't be 2021-01-09

Comment: I don't think that HAVING clause is doing what you expect after joining b to all prior rows of a.  Perhaps you want to skip the join and just use a window function to get running total, e.g. `SUM(a.PaymentAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY a.CustomerCode, a.CustomerType ORDER BY a.PaymentAmount`

Comment: @Paradox what is the expected output ?

Comment: @SelVazi 2023-01-07

Answer (score 3):

The initial intent of your query is to compute the running sum of payments for each customer. I would recommend rephrasing your code to use window functions rather than a self-join. This is neater, and much more efficient:

```
select p.*,
    sum(amount) over(order by PaymentDate) sum_amount
from payment p
where CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
```

For a given customer, we can just filter the resultset for negative values, order it by date and retain the top row only:

```
select top (1) *
from (
    select p.*,
        sum(amount) over(order by PaymentDate) sum_amount
    from payment p
    where CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
) p
where sum_amount < 0
order by PaymentDate
```

I am not totally sure if you want to use a partition to compute the running sum (your query joins on `CustomerCode` and `CustomerType`, but filters on `CustomerCode` only). If you wanted the same result for multiple customers, we would use:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from (
    select p.*,
        sum(amount) over(partition by CustomerCode order by PaymentDate) sum_amount
    from payment p
) p
where sum_amount < 0
order by row_number() over(partition by CustomerCode order by PaymentDate)
```

---

Update: you want the latest date when each customer's balance became negative (whereas above queries give you the *earliest* date). We can just tweak the `where` and `order by` clauses for this:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from (
    select p.*,
        sum(amount) over(partition by CustomerCode order by PaymentDate) sum_amount
    from payment p
) p
where sum_amount < 0            -- the balance is negative now
  and sum_amount - amount >= 0  -- and it was positive before
order by row_number() 
    over(partition by CustomerCode order by PaymentDate desc) 
                                -- ^ descending sort to put latest dates first
```

Comment: Good answer. `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, in case there are duplicates in the ordering, it's also faster.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I think the second `order by PaymentDate` should be desc since right now that returns the first negative value.  But even changing to desc, this would return the most recent negative value.  What I am looking for is the most recent time it changed to a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the most recent time it changed to a negative value :

So using this query we can clearly say that the most recent time it changed to a negative is `2023-01-07` :

```
select *
from (
  select p.*,
        sum(PaymentAmount) over(order by PaymentDate) as running_sum
  from Payments p
  where CustomerCode = 123
) as s
```

Result :

```
CustomerCode    PaymentDate     PaymentAmount   running_sum
123 retail      2023-01-01      0               0
123 retail      2023-01-02      10              10
123 retail      2023-01-03      -30             -20
123 retail      2023-01-04      10              -10
123 retail      2023-01-05      20              10
123 retail      2023-01-06      10              20
123 retail      2023-01-07      -40             -20     <-- most recent time it changed to a negative value
123 retail      2023-01-08      -10             -30
123 retail      2023-01-09      10              80
123 retail      2023-01-09      100             80
```

o obtain the expected date, we must group successive rows and then select the first date from the most recent group :

```
select top (1) CustomerCode, CustomerType, PaymentDate, PaymentAmount
from (
      select *, sum(case when falling = 1 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by PaymentDate) as grp
      from (
             select *, case when running_sum < 0 then 1 else null end as falling
             from (
                 select p.*, sum(PaymentAmount) over(order by PaymentDate) as running_sum,
                 row_number() over(order by PaymentDate) as rn
                 from Payments p
                 where CustomerCode = 123
             ) as c1
      ) as c2
) as c3
where running_sum < 0
order by grp desc, rn
```

Result :

```
CustomerCode    CustomerType    PaymentDate PaymentAmount
123             retail          2023-01-07  -40
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/C4KLEB1l)